# How can I add a custom price to a cart as an attribute of product type in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

How can I add **custom price** to cart as an attribute of **product type** in [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)?

In detail am creating a custom tshirt design UI where user have the options to design a tshirt(add image,text etc) and add to cart. I have loaded all the products in the site to the UI and user have the option to add  product to cart after designing. User is charged with an extra amount for designing like adding each images to tshirt which increases the base price of tshirt. But my issue is that the products get added to cart with the base price. I have used the folowing code to add the product to cart.

```
commerce_cart_product_add_by_id($pid, $quan, $combine = TRUE, $uid);
```

When I searched and found that there is no way to add the custom price as parameter of the above function so that the altered price gets added to cart. But found another solution that it can be done by adding as an attribute of the product.

**How can I  map the custom price I have created as an attribute of the product and add to cart for altering the price section?**

Comment: Why does this have to be "programmatically"? Consider editng your question to explain the reason for that (or reword the question so that that does not appear to be a "must") ....

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens  I just wanted to know how can I alter the price in the cart programatically?

Comment: What are you using the store the custom prices? Any chance you have a URL where this can be observed in action?

Comment: OK, now the question seems ok to me (and it leaves an option open to yes/no do it programatically) ... +1!

Comment: @Brady custom price is stored using a variable in js file. $(".sample_icons").click(function(){
  
  pr1 = pr1 + 2;
  xr=xr+2;
  alert(pr1);
  var $srcimg=$(this).children("img").attr('src');
  image_icon($srcimg);
  
  });  when the click function for adding an image to the tshirt is used, price increases by certain amount. here the variable is pr1 and it increases by 2 for each addition of image.

Comment: @Brady Sorry I dont have a url for you to show my project since am doing it on a local server.

Comment: Ah! Ok now that helps. The custom price is coming from a source outside of Drupal modules. Are you storing this data in the Drupal.settings JS object? I've got an idea on how to do this if the information is accessible to Drupal core processes. You might could use rules to do this.

Comment: Are you opposed to a custom module? I think that will be the only way to accomplish this being the values for the products is being manipulated in JS. You are going to have to pull the data into Drupal so you can add it to the prices in the cart which can be done (you add a value to a base price of a product, this comes in a rule supplied by DC).

Comment: I am using a custom module for my UI to integrate wih drupal. The updated value of price is stored in a variable in a js file which i have been mentioned earlier and is available globally.

Answer (score 1):

Below these modules will help you with bit of customization or addons

[**Commerce Product Attributes**](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes)

> This module provides some enhancements to the Drupal Commerce
>   attribute handling.

[**Commerce Product Option**](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option)

> This module allows you to add user-customizable options to the
>   commerce "add to cart" form. You do this by defining "option sets", to
>   which you can attach any field of your choosing. These option sets can
>   then be added to your commerce products using entity reference, after
>   which the fields in your option set will show up in the add to cart
>   form.

**[Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes)**

> This module provides some enhancements to the Commerce Product Option
>   and Commerce Product Attributes handling by applying pricing rules to
>   custom product attributes. So, you can add attributes to products that
>   affect the final product price.

Comment: I have created a custom UI for this project. All the addition of products to cart takes place in this UI through custom module. How  the modules mentioned above by you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Drupal Commerce's core product pricing rules system as explained in the [Product Pricing Rules](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-pricing-rules-screencasts) documentation (on DrupalCommerce.org). This is the only supported way to make consistent line item unit price alterations that are reflected in the final order total.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following functions :

```
 $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, $quantity, $order_id, $data = array(), $type);

// You can add the required additional price components here.

    //Later using the following function will create the line item with the required price.

    commerce_cart_product_add($uid, $line_item, $combine = TRUE);
```

//If you insist on changing the Base price of the products and not adding price components to Line item then you need to include Price change logic into the line item refresh hook.

Get more details on this hook :
http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.api.php/function/hook_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh/DC

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links. May be this will be useful.

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_rebase_unit_price/7

https://www.drupal.org/node/1719316